# Adding dynamically added field values along with form values in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have an component called `demo`, which as some i/p fields: 
**first name,last name,number....**  along with these fields i am **dynamically adding** the 2 fields (i,e to add multiple address).

> **I am able to send the all form fields value but not the dynamically added values**.

While **logging** the dynamically added field values are displaying as `undefined`. Since the component's code is long, I am posting stackblitz [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-nfiegg?file=app/demo/demo.component.css).

Comment: which 2 fields are you talking about? addresses are the array.

Comment: Just fill all `input fields` and also the `dynamic fields` and hit the `Save` button then see the `console`, Then you can understand my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As addresstype is array and your will not be able to get it easily,

```
  addFieldValue() {
   if (this.newAttribute.adr && this.newAttribute.city) {
     if (this.fieldArray.indexOf(this.newAttribute) === -1) {
    this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute)
    }
  }

   this.newAttribute = {};//see here
  }
```

Here you are actually emptying the value so the values will be always 0.

But you are already putting the values in the fieldArray, you can easily retrieve the array values by iterating over it and getting the values.

```
  public onAdd(): void {
    this.someContact = this.addForm.value;
    this.someContact.phoneNumbers = [];
    const phno: IPhoneNumber = {
      countryCode: this.addForm.value.counrtycode,
      number: this.addForm.value.phonenumber,
    };
    this.someContact.phoneNumbers.push(phno);

    this.someContact.addresses = [];
    this.fieldArray.forEach(a => {
      const addr: IPostalAddress = {
        addtype: a.adr,
        city: a.city,
      };
      this.someContact.addresses.push(addr);
    })


    console.log(this.someContact);
  }
```

I changed `type` to `addtype`, looks bad naming.

```
export interface IPostalAddress {
  addtype:            string;
  city:            string;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-uyx1gw)

Note: as you are not dealing with the forms you can remove `formControlName="adrType"`

Comment: Thanks for answer and also for your valuable explanation regarding my issue.